# Renaming attribute/field names in GeoPackage Layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geopackage

I need to rename the attribute field names in a GeoPackage layer by using Python QGIS 3.2.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.